# Why can't we run Get method of requests vs RequestsLibrary Library in Robot Framework together

Tags: json, robotframework

## Here is code:

```
*** Settings ***

Library  Collections
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  requests

# Declare Test case 
*** Test Cases ***

Get Requests2

    ${resp2}=   Get  http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN
    ${convert_to_json2}=   set variable  ${resp2.json()}
    log to console  ${convert_to_json2}
```

## it displays the follwing error Multiple keywords with name 'Get' found. Give the full name of the keyword you want to use: RequestsLibrary.Get   requests.Get`

Comment: [Handling keywords with the same name](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#handling-keywords-with-same-names)

Comment: I just noticed this question was a duplicate, please refrain from asking the same question twice in the future @madhur

Comment: @verv , please go through  the answer and conversation between me and Bryan for the question which you see duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries likely both contain the same keyword, or rather they both have a keyword that use the same name. In order to identify which keyword you want to call, Robot Framework needs to have only unique names in it's keywords namespace.

As the error suggests, you can prefix the library's name before the keyword name, to allow Robot Framework to differentiate the two keywords:

```
*** Test Cases ***

Get Requests2

    ${resp2}=   RequestsLibrary.Get  http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN
    ${convert_to_json2}=   set variable  ${resp2.json()}
    log to console  ${convert_to_json2}
```

Or,

```
*** Test Cases ***

Get Requests2

    ${resp2}=   requests.Get  http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN
    ${convert_to_json2}=   set variable  ${resp2.json()}
    log to console  ${convert_to_json2}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. What is difference between Get and Get Request method in RequestLibrary. i checked both method both have same parameter except Json is not included in Get method.